# Formatting SelectLayerByAttribute_management where clause

Tags: arcpy, select-by-attribute, error-000358

I have two shapefile layers in my arcMAP project, "TP_Input" and "union". The latter has the associated layer "unionOutputLyr". I am trying to do a simple select by attributes but the one associated with unionOutputLyr consistently fails with Error 358 (last six lines). I did the same query to see if it works with TP_input and it does (1st six lines).

```
selectFeature = "ShapeArea"
expr_value = 500.0
expression = """{0} > {1}""".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(TP_Input, selectFeature),expr_value)
arcpy.AddMessage(expression)
res = arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management (TP_Input, "NEW_SELECTION", expression)
arcpy.AddMessage("Select 99:"+str(int(arcpy.GetCount_management(res).getOutput(0))))

selectFeature = "ShapeArea"
expr_value = 500.0
expression = """{0} > {1}""".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(unionOutputLyr, selectFeature),expr_value)
arcpy.AddMessage(expression)
res = arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management (unionOutputLyr, "NEW_SELECTION", expression)
arcpy.AddMessage("Select 2:"+str(int(arcpy.GetCount_management(res).getOutput(0))))
```

The expression is:
"ShapeArea" > 500.0 and it works for the one, but not the other.

I  can switch "ShapeArea" to "FID" and expr_value to 10 and it works fine for the second select. ShapeArea is defined as DOUBLE for both fields.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro or with ArcMap?

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question to specify the data format. Each different format has a different SQL provider, so the syntax can vary.

Comment: Please update your question to include the output that you get from each of your `arcpy.AddMessage(expression)` lines.

Comment: What data type is ShapeArea in the unionOutputLyr and is ShapeArea definitely an existing field in the layer? Also, little tip, you do not need to use GetCount. SelectLayerByAttribute returns a count of the selection (check the docs derived output section of the tool), you can access in your code with res[1]